# How to design database with the default data that can be overwritten in some cases

Tags: sql

I'm designing the database model for the delivery application.

I have a DeliveryWeek entity that represents a single week and a DeliveryDay entity that represents a day of the week (Monday-Friday).
There is also a DeliveryWeekDay entity that joins DeliveryWeek and DeliveryDay in many-to-many relationship.

There is also DeliveryHour entity and DeliveryDayHour entity that joins DeliveryDay and DeliveryHour in many-to-many relationship.

For most of the weeks delivery hours are the same but, in some cases, (holiday week) they might be different.

I want to be able to modify default delivery hours for all new DeliveryWeeks but for some DeliveryWeeks these hours can be overwritten.

Should I use two separate tables? For example DefaultDeliveryHours for the default values and every time when I create a new DeliveryWeek I should make a new DeliveryHour entries based on DefaultDeliveryHour data?

Comment: Could you please give us an example of your DeliveryDay properties?

Comment: I've updated the description

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways you could go:

First is without DeliveryWeekDay:

```
---------------      -------------
| DeliveryWeek|      |DeliveryDay|
|-------------|      |-----------|
|Year (PK)    |      |Id (PK)    |
|Weeknr (PK)  |      |Weekday    |
|MonId        |--->  |Properties |
|TueId        |--->  -------------
|WedId        |--->
|ThuId        |--->
|FriId        |--->
---------------
```

Via the id you could define different DeliveryDays with different properties. Your code (program or sql trigger) should then make sure that MonId only references monday weekdays etc. for the other weekdays!

The second variant would be with a DeliveryWeekDay relation table - which looks like:

```
---------------    -----------------    -------------
| DeliveryWeek|    |DeliveryWeekDay|    |DeliveryDay|
|-------------|    |---------------|    |-----------|
|Year (PK)    |<---|Year (PK/FK)   |--->|Id (PK)    |
|Weeknr (PK)  |    |Weeknr (PK(FK) |    |Weekday    |
---------------    |DDayId (PK/FK) |    |Properties |
                   -----------------    -------------
```

Here you also have to make sure that your code (program vs sql trigger) makes sure that for every DeliveryWeek there are 5 entries (for every weekday) within your DeliveryWeekDay table - except if there is a holiday within that week.

In both ways you could make DeliveryDay.Id = 1 the default and use other id values for your special cases.

The same concept goes for your DeliveryHour table. Please don't use an extra default table, because it is only a redundant one.

Comment: I was already heading to the second approach. The real problem is how to store the default DeliveryHour values for Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are using the "DeliveryWeekDay" entity as reference. 
You could design your "DeliveryWeekDay" like this:
ID,DeliveryWeekID,DeliveryDayID,DeliveryHoursID, DefaultDayID, DefaultHoursID.

So if "DeliveryDayID" is null you return "DefaultDayID" and if "DeliveryHoursID" is null you could return "DefaultHoursID". Assuming you query by SQL:

```
SELECT ID,DeliveryWeekID,ISNULL(DeliveryDayID,DefaultDayID),ISNULL(DeliveryHoursID,DefaultHoursID)
```

This way you can have default value but also change the default for some entries.